# WooCommerce order received page returns 404

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce is adding a `page_id` query argument to the order-received page redirect causing it to throw a 404 error.

The url looks like this `/order-received/?page_id=1489&key=wc_order_HZSn6X66YKgUy`.

I have tried flushing the rewrite rules in the permalinks section and redirecting page using the `woocommerce_thankyou` hook, both of these have not worked.